# Rails relationship.build not working on Many-to-Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three resources (slight caveat is that User is associated to Devise gem, details of which I've left out since I dont think they're relevant.

users <-> memberships <-> groups

require 'digest/sha2'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :memberships_attributes

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  attr_accessible :memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end


class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessible  :user, :group
end


class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through=>:memberships
end
```

The problem is that build is not using the attributes I'm providing, specifically for **group_id**. I'm pasting the output of the debugger:

```
(rdb:1903) @user.memberships.build(:group_id=>1)
#<Membership id: nil, user_id: 5, group_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I know the relationships/ORM mappings are good because I can do this:

```
(rdb:1903) @user.memberships.first.group_id=1
1
(rdb:1903) @user.memberships.first
#<Membership id: nil, user_id: 5, **group_id: 1**, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I've tried this on a simple has_many demo app, and it works fine.

---

**ANSWER: It was solved by updating memberships model to have:**

```
attr_accessible  :user, :group, :group_id
```

Comment: Does this group exist (is saved)? In MTM relationships, the associated objects must be saved first.

Comment: yes, it does exist  (rdb:1903) @user.memberships.first.group
#<Group id: 1, title: "Default", created_at: "2011-03-22 12:27:52", updated_at: "2011-03-22 12:27:52">

Comment: Can you post your full model code for each model, there might be something else interfering.

Comment: just updated it with full model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the attributes are protected, you are not able to mass-assign to them using `new`, `build`, `attributes=` or `update_attributes`. This may be blocking your `group_id` assignment.

Comment: I was accessing group_id and did not have that in the memberships model. Adding the following to memberships model made it work  attr_accessible  :user, :group, :group_id